# How do I place the tooltip in the fancybox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tooltip, fancybox

this is my tooltip

title='

##### Fare conditions 2

1 Adult, Standard Class, Super Off-Peak Single, Semi-Flexible:
Valid only for travel via (changing trains or passing through) London. Ticket restrictions available at http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/1L. Break of journey allowed. Includes transfer across London by London Underground, Docklands Light Railway or Thameslink appropriate to the route of your through journey. Refundable up to 28 days after ticket expiry with a £10 fee.

'>

Comment: And to which element do you want to add tooltip?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.